# Visual Studio on MAC OS 10.5.2 does not show a dialog box when I use "Add > Add files from folder"

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin

Has anyone come across this problem.

In VS when I enter Add > Add files from folder then the file dialog box does not appear to allow me pick a file.

> === Visual Studio Community 2019 for Mac ===
>
> Version 8.3.11 (build 1) Installation UUID:
>   257e0139-f078-416b-9cad-d4ed65853d23  GTK+ 2.24.23 (Raleigh theme)
>     Xamarin.Mac 5.16.1.24 (d16-3 / 08809f5b)
>
> Package version: 604000208
>
> === Mono Framework MDK ===
>
> Runtime:  Mono 6.4.0.208 (2019-06/07c23f2ca43) (64-bit)   Package
>   version: 604000208
>
> === NuGet ===
>
> Version: 5.3.0.6192
>
> === .NET Core SDK ===
>
> SDK: /usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/3.0.101/Sdks SDK Versions:
>     3.0.101
>     2.1.700
>     2.1.505 MSBuild SDKs: /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/6.4.0/lib/mono/msbuild/Current/bin/Sdks
>
> === .NET Core Runtime ===
>
> Runtime: /usr/local/share/dotnet/dotnet Runtime Versions:
>     3.0.1
>     2.1.14
>     2.1.11
>     2.1.9
>
> === Xamarin.Profiler ===
>
> Version: 1.6.12.29 Location: /Applications/Xamarin
>   Profiler.app/Contents/MacOS/Xamarin Profiler
>
> === Updater ===
>
> Version: 11
>
> === Xamarin.Android ===
>
> Version: 10.0.6.2 (Visual Studio Community) Commit:
>   xamarin-android/d16-3/c407838 Android SDK:
>   /Users/marilousargado/Library/Developer/Xamarin/android-sdk-macosx
>     Supported Android versions:
>         8.1 (API level 27)
>
> SDK Tools Version: 26.1.1 SDK Platform Tools Version: 28.0.0 SDK Build
>   Tools Version: 27.0.3
>
> Build Information:  Mono: mono/mono/2019-06@476d72b9e32 Java.Interop:
>   xamarin/java.interop/d16-3@5836f58 LibZipSharp:
>   grendello/LibZipSharp/d16-3@71f4a94 LibZip:
>   nih-at/libzip/rel-1-5-1@b95cf3fd ProGuard:
>   xamarin/proguard/master@905836d SQLite: xamarin/sqlite/3.27.1@8212a2d
>   Xamarin.Android Tools: xamarin/xamarin-android-tools/d16-3@cb41333
>
> === Microsoft Mobile OpenJDK ===
>
> Java SDK:
>   /Users/marilousargado/Library/Developer/Xamarin/jdk/microsoft_dist_openjdk_1.8.0.25
>   1.8.0-25 Android Designer EPL code available here: https://github.com/xamarin/AndroidDesigner.EPL
>
> === Android SDK Manager ===
>
> Version: 1.4.0.65 Hash: c33b107 Branch: remotes/origin/d16-3 Build
>   date: 2019-11-19 20:33:22 UTC
>
> === Android Device Manager ===
>
> Version: 1.2.0.116 Hash: d2b2af0 Branch: remotes/origin/d16-3 Build
>   date: 2019-11-19 20:33:42 UTC
>
> === Apple Developer Tools ===
>
> Xcode 11.3 (15712) Build 11C29
>
> === Xamarin.Mac ===
>
> Xamarin.Mac not installed. Can't find
>   /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.Mac.framework/Versions/Current/Version.
>
> === Xamarin.iOS ===
>
> Version: 13.6.0.12 (Visual Studio Community) Hash: e3c2b406d Branch:
>   xcode11.2 Build date: 2019-11-01 00:12:08-0400
>
> === Xamarin Designer ===
>
> Version: 16.3.0.256 Hash: 8a223bfd7 Branch: remotes/origin/d16-3 Build
>   date: 2019-11-01 21:02:02 UTC
>
> === Xamarin Inspector ===
>
> Version: 1.4.3 Hash: db27525 Branch: 1.4-release Build date: Mon, 09
>   Jul 2018 21:20:18 GMT Client compatibility: 1
>
> === Build Information ===
>
> Release ID: 803110001 Git revision:
>   6ee6ad2ec46ae5a08a1999ee4c815ac656a35b91 Build date: 2019-12-05
>   16:09:27+00 Build branch: release-8.3 Xamarin extensions:
>   56bd70ef2e327f71c615cfc29a47fd50685fadcb
>
> === Operating System ===
>
> Mac OS X 10.14.5 Darwin 18.6.0 Darwin Kernel Version 18.6.0
>       Thu Apr 25 23:16:27 PDT 2019
>       root:xnu-4903.261.4~2/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64

So when I do this and click then nothing happens:

[image]

Comment: You might be more likely to get an answer on [the Apple stack exchange](https://apple.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score 0):

For VS for Mac , you should select the folder which contains the file you want to add .

And you will see the following image

[image]

It contains all files and folders in the folder which you select . Then you can check the file as you want .

Comment: Yes I've done this 100 time but my point is that as of right now the "Select files to add from shared" dialog box no longer appears.  I tried a reinstall of VS and still the same so I can only assume it's a problem with the MAC OS :-( I will be interested to see if others experience the same issue going forward.